# Sqoop: Understanding how num-mappers and fetch-size work together

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to import a table from MySQL incrementally using following configuration:

```
--split-by
date_format(updated_at, '%l')
--boundary-query
select 1, 12 from ${table}
--m
12
--incremental
lastmodified
--last-value
${lastValue}
--check-column
updated_at
--merge-key
id
```

When I run this, I am getting `Java Heap Space` error. After searching a bit, I got to know about another config `--fetch-size <n>`, which defaults to `1000`, in sqoop which controls the number number of entries to read from database at once.

Default container memory allocation is 1 GB and the table which I am pulling is of size around 100 GB.

I am trying to figure out why its throwing `Java Heap Space` error as I am sure if it is going to pull 1000 rows at once, data size of 1000 rows is not going to exceed 1GB.

Is `fetch-data` config being overwritten by by the `split-by, boundary-query and mapper` config?

Idea behind this config was to ensure that data distribution is now skewed and few mappers only don't end up pulling all the data. So with this config, I am doing a `split` by `hour` in 12 hour format so that hour 1 and 13 get assigned to same mapper.

Any guidance on this will be really helpful.